# Prove that $X_{v+w} \subset X_v+X_w$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $B \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ a set convex and simetric, ($B=-B$). Prove that $X_{v+w} \subset X_v+X_w$, where
$$X_v= \{ \alpha >0 \ ; \ \frac{1}{\alpha}v \in B \}$$
$$X_w=\{\varepsilon >0 \ ; \ \frac{1}{\varepsilon}w \in B \}$$
$$X_{v+w}=\{\lambda >0 \ ; \ \frac{1}{\lambda}(v+w) \in B\}.$$ Thanks!!

Comment: I can't to get that if $\frac{1}{\lambda}(v+w) \in B$ then $\frac{1}{\lambda}v$ or $\frac{1}{\lambda}w \in B$.

Comment: I need of this resutate to prove that $||v||=\inf\{\lambda >0 \ ; \  \frac{1}{\lambda}v\in B\}$ it is a norm in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (inequality triangular)... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't true. Take $B=\mathbb R u$ with $u\in\mathbb R^d\setminus\{0\}$. 
$B$ is convex and symmetric.

Take two vectors $v$ and $w$ that aren't in $B$ such that $v+w$ is.

Then $X_v$ and $X_w$ are empty but $X_{v+w}$ is not.

Note : You probably want $0$ to be in the interior of $B$!

---

Addition : Let $\Vert x\Vert=\inf\{\lambda>0 : \dfrac 1\lambda x\in B\}$

You want to prove that $\Vert x+y\Vert \leq \Vert x\Vert + \Vert y\Vert$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $\Bbb R^d$

Hint : Take $\lambda>0$ and $\mu>0$ s.t. $\dfrac 1\lambda x\in B$ and $\dfrac 1\mu y\in B$

Use $\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}+\dfrac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}=1$ and the convexity of $B$ to prove that $\dfrac 1{\lambda+\mu}(x+y)\in B$.

Hence $\Vert x+y\Vert \leq \lambda+\mu$, and you can finish easily.

Comment: This isn't true: $0 \in B$ aways, because let $v \in B$, $-v \in B$ (simetric) and taking $t=\frac{1}{2} \in [0,1]$ we have $\frac{1}{2}v-\frac{1}{2}v=0 \in B$, as B is convex.

Comment: @Jarbas: Yes, since $B$ is symmetric and convex, then $0\in B$ so long as $B$ is non-empty. There is a difference between having $0\in B$ and having $0$ in the *interior* of $B$, though.

Comment: ok. then... how prove i the triangular inequality of norm???

Comment: I've added a few remarks to my answer.